# Why ESLint trigger error on useEffect dependancy array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I installed ESLint into VS code and in my React project it wants to make correction when i use useEffect. The segment of the code is:

```js
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            navigate("/");
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

The ESLint underline me isAuthenticated inside of the dependancy array of useEffect and tells me that:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

So i dont know how actualy dependancy array of useEffect work or this is some sort of missunderstaning of eslint ?

P.S. Long story short that i know about this array is there is staying thinks that trigger this useEffect when they are changed. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you're right. Putting that variable at the end of useEffect means that, the effect runs when dependency variable value changes.

ESLint is providing a warning because it detects that the navigate function is used inside the useEffect callback, but it's not listed as a dependency in the dependency array.

Include the navigate function from the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigate("/");
    }
}, [isAuthenticated, navigate]); // Add 'navigate' to the dependency array
```

**OR, you can Disable the ESLint rule for the specific line:**

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigate("/");
    }
}, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Let me know, if you still having the issue.

Comment: It works both ways but how it is more correctly to do it? Is that mean i should put every function that i am useing in useEffect into dependancy array and also why eslint wants that. Is there possibility navigate to be changed and that trigger useEffect or just we should put every used in useEffect function in that array?

Comment: Not at all. It doesn't mean to put everything in useEffect as a dependency, cause It might lead to broke some of functionalities by extra re-rendering. Just Disable the ESLint rule for that specific use case.